# How can I find which of my code cause the SIGABRT in pthread_crate.c file, but without any my code information in the coredump

Tags: c, linux, gdb, pthreads, coredump

There is a coredump caused by my program, which shows below:

```
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/libthread_db.so.1".
Core was generated by `./remote_speaker plug:SLAVE='dmix:tlv320aic3106au' default rtmp://pili-publish.'.
Program terminated with signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
#0  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:50
50      ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
[Current thread is 1 (Thread 0xffff802791d0 (LWP 1511))]
(gdb) bt
#0  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:50
#1  0x0000ffff812b9f54 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:79
#2  0x0000ffff81304d3c in __libc_message (action=action@entry=do_abort, fmt=fmt@entry=0xffff813bf638 "%s\n") at ../sysdeps/posix/libc_fatal.c:181
#3  0x0000ffff8130c32c in malloc_printerr (str=str@entry=0xffff813bafb0 "free(): invalid pointer") at malloc.c:5332
#4  0x0000ffff8130db04 in _int_free (av=0xffff813fb9f8 <main_arena>, p=0xffff7d783ff0, have_lock=<optimized out>) at malloc.c:4173
#5  0x0000ffff81310b50 in tcache_thread_shutdown () at malloc.c:2964
#6  __malloc_arena_thread_freeres () at arena.c:949
#7  0x0000ffff81313e8c in __libc_thread_freeres () at thread-freeres.c:38
#8  0x0000ffff81614844 in start_thread (arg=0xffffc2f50ff6) at pthread_create.c:493
#9  0x0000ffff81365a7c in thread_start () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/aarch64/clone.S:78
(gdb)
```

The total threads info shows below:

```
(gdb) info threads 
  Id   Target Id                        Frame 
* 1    Thread 0xffff802791d0 (LWP 1511) __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:50
  2    Thread 0xffff80a7a1d0 (LWP 1510) 0x0000ffff8135d084 in __GI___poll (fds=0xffff80a79740, nfds=1, timeout=<optimized out>) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/poll.c:41
  3    Thread 0xffff8127c010 (LWP 1492) 0x0000ffff81339d88 in __GI___nanosleep (requested_time=requested_time@entry=0xffffc2f510a0, remaining=remaining@entry=0x0)
    at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/nanosleep.c:28
  4    Thread 0xffff7e2751d0 (LWP 1515) 0x0000ffff81365bcc in __GI_epoll_pwait (epfd=6, events=0x594160 <self+128>, maxevents=32, timeout=100, set=0x0)
    at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/epoll_pwait.c:42
  5    Thread 0xffff8127b1d0 (LWP 1509) futex_abstimed_wait_cancelable (private=0, abstime=0x0, clockid=0, expected=0, futex_word=0x596538 <output_notice>)
    at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/futex-internal.h:208
  6    Thread 0xffff7fa781d0 (LWP 1512) 0x0000ffff81339d84 in __GI___nanosleep (requested_time=requested_time@entry=0xffff7fa77870, remaining=remaining@entry=0xffff7fa77870)
    at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/nanosleep.c:28
```

thread 1-6

```
(gdb) thread 1
[Switching to thread 1 (Thread 0xffff802791d0 (LWP 1511))]
#0  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:50
50      in ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c
(gdb) bt
#0  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:50
#1  0x0000ffff812b9f54 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:79
#2  0x0000ffff81304d3c in __libc_message (action=action@entry=do_abort, fmt=fmt@entry=0xffff813bf638 "%s\n") at ../sysdeps/posix/libc_fatal.c:181
#3  0x0000ffff8130c32c in malloc_printerr (str=str@entry=0xffff813bafb0 "free(): invalid pointer") at malloc.c:5332
#4  0x0000ffff8130db04 in _int_free (av=0xffff813fb9f8 <main_arena>, p=0xffff7d783ff0, have_lock=<optimized out>) at malloc.c:4173
#5  0x0000ffff81310b50 in tcache_thread_shutdown () at malloc.c:2964
#6  __malloc_arena_thread_freeres () at arena.c:949
#7  0x0000ffff81313e8c in __libc_thread_freeres () at thread-freeres.c:38
#8  0x0000ffff81614844 in start_thread (arg=0xffffc2f50ff6) at pthread_create.c:493
#9  0x0000ffff81365a7c in thread_start () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/aarch64/clone.S:78
(gdb) thread 2
[Switching to thread 2 (Thread 0xffff80a7a1d0 (LWP 1510))]
#0  0x0000ffff8135d084 in __GI___poll (fds=0xffff80a79740, nfds=1, timeout=<optimized out>) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/poll.c:41
41      ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/poll.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000ffff8135d084 in __GI___poll (fds=0xffff80a79740, nfds=1, timeout=<optimized out>) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/poll.c:41
#1  0x00000000004e8714 in nn_efd_wait ()
#2  0x00000000004e46a0 in nn_sock_recv ()
#3  0x00000000004e24b0 in nn_recvmsg ()
#4  0x00000000004e1ef4 in nn_recv ()
#5  0x0000000000445c2c in nanomsg_recv ()
#6  0x0000ffff816148f8 in start_thread (arg=0xffffc2f50ff6) at pthread_create.c:479
#7  0x0000ffff81365a7c in thread_start () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/aarch64/clone.S:78
(gdb) thread 3
[Switching to thread 3 (Thread 0xffff8127c010 (LWP 1492))]
#0  0x0000ffff81339d88 in __GI___nanosleep (requested_time=requested_time@entry=0xffffc2f510a0, remaining=remaining@entry=0x0) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/nanosleep.c:28
28      ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/nanosleep.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000ffff81339d88 in __GI___nanosleep (requested_time=requested_time@entry=0xffffc2f510a0, remaining=remaining@entry=0x0) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/nanosleep.c:28
#1  0x0000ffff8135fb54 in usleep (useconds=<optimized out>) at ../sysdeps/posix/usleep.c:32
#2  0x0000000000434278 in main ()
(gdb) thread 4
[Switching to thread 4 (Thread 0xffff7e2751d0 (LWP 1515))]
#0  0x0000ffff81365bcc in __GI_epoll_pwait (epfd=6, events=0x594160 <self+128>, maxevents=32, timeout=100, set=0x0) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/epoll_pwait.c:42
42      ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/epoll_pwait.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000ffff81365bcc in __GI_epoll_pwait (epfd=6, events=0x594160 <self+128>, maxevents=32, timeout=100, set=0x0) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/epoll_pwait.c:42
#1  0x00000000004f2a14 in nn_poller_wait ()
#2  0x00000000004e712c in nn_worker_routine ()
#3  0x00000000004e9eb8 in nn_thread_main_routine ()
#4  0x0000ffff816148f8 in start_thread (arg=0xffff80a796c6) at pthread_create.c:479
#5  0x0000ffff81365a7c in thread_start () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/aarch64/clone.S:78
(gdb) thread 5
[Switching to thread 5 (Thread 0xffff8127b1d0 (LWP 1509))]
#0  futex_abstimed_wait_cancelable (private=0, abstime=0x0, clockid=0, expected=0, futex_word=0x596538 <output_notice>) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/futex-internal.h:208
208     ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/futex-internal.h: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  futex_abstimed_wait_cancelable (private=0, abstime=0x0, clockid=0, expected=0, futex_word=0x596538 <output_notice>) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/futex-internal.h:208
#1  do_futex_wait (sem=sem@entry=0x596538 <output_notice>, abstime=0x0, clockid=0) at sem_waitcommon.c:112
#2  0x0000ffff8161dd10 in __new_sem_wait_slow (sem=0x596538 <output_notice>, abstime=0x0, clockid=0) at sem_waitcommon.c:184
#3  0x0000000000529aa8 in async_output ()
#4  0x0000ffff816148f8 in start_thread (arg=0xffffc2f50fa6) at pthread_create.c:479
#5  0x0000ffff81365a7c in thread_start () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/aarch64/clone.S:78
(gdb) thread 6
[Switching to thread 6 (Thread 0xffff7fa781d0 (LWP 1512))]
#0  0x0000ffff81339d84 in __GI___nanosleep (requested_time=requested_time@entry=0xffff7fa77870, remaining=remaining@entry=0xffff7fa77870) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/nanosleep.c:28
28      ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/nanosleep.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000ffff81339d84 in __GI___nanosleep (requested_time=requested_time@entry=0xffff7fa77870, remaining=remaining@entry=0xffff7fa77870) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/nanosleep.c:28
#1  0x0000ffff81339c14 in __sleep (seconds=0) at ../sysdeps/posix/sleep.c:55
#2  0x0000000000434ee0 in play_sound ()
#3  0x0000ffff816148f8 in start_thread (arg=0xffffc2f50ff6) at pthread_create.c:479
#4  0x0000ffff81365a7c in thread_start () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/aarch64/clone.S:78
```

I am sorry that I can not post the source code, because the code is a little much important for us.

**The question is that I can not find which of my code caused this dump.** There is no any my code in thread 1 after the pthread_create function. For a normal way, there must be some of my code in the threads, Is that right?

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I should attach that this phenomenon is not Appearing-Certain.

Comment: I also faced the issue, issue is because when thread destructor is called and the thread is neither joined nor detached then std::terminate is called which calls abort().
I am still trying to figure out which thread is failing like this. Did you find any solution?

Comment: sorry, I do not have any solution. @AbinashKumar

Answer (score 1):

> The question is that I can not find which of my code caused this dump

Any crash inside `malloc` or `free` is a 99.9% sign of heap corruption (`free`ing something twice, `free`ing unallocated memory, writing past the end of allocated buffer, etc.).

Here you have `free()` telling you that you are `free`ing something that was not allocated. The address being `free`d: `0xffff7d783ff0` looks like a stack address. It is *probable* that you have `free`d some stack address earlier.

Unfortunately, it is nearly impossible to debug heap corruption via post-mortem debugging, because the root cause of corruption may have happened 1000s of instructions earlier, possibly in completely unrelated code.

The good news: instrumenting your program with address sanitizer (`gcc -fsanitize=address ...`) and running such program through your tests (you do have tests, right?) *usually* leads you straight to the problem.

Comment: Yeap, many people and online forum are said like you. It may be other bug caused this crash. And I have test the asan tool on my code, but there is not any wrong when running. That makes me bald.